# convert ushort[] grayscale values to byte[]

Tags: c#, byte, grayscale, ushort

I have `uhort[]` values in the format `0-65536`. But I need this grayscale values in byte form!

How can I convert my ushort values in byte values?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 byte value = (byte)(array[index] >> 8);
```